# Input text box and button inside not responsive

Tags: html, css, button, input

When I resize my browser, the button breaks up from inside the text box and goes under it. How do I keep it inside the text box at all times? Thanks!

```css
#search-row {
  padding-top: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 200px;
  margin-right: 45px;
  width: auto;
}

#search {
  width: 575px;
  height: 70px;
  position: relative;
}

#submit {
  margin-left: -100px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="search-row">
  <input id="search" type="search" placeholder="What instrument do you want to learn" />
  <button id="submit" type="submit">Search</button>
</div>
```

Comment: that's a really weird layout. When the search string gets long enough, text will be behind the button... are you sure you want to go with that?

Comment: I'm adding a maxlength to the input box so that wont happen. What layout would you suggest

Comment: hmm but autocomplete by the brosers will still appear over the button... Why don't just simply use the input and button side by side?

Answer (score 1):

That would cause the long searches to stack behind the button, and browsers autocomplete to appear over it.

Why don't go with an inline form? with flexbox it's easy as pie

```css
#search-row {
 margin-top: 45px;
 display:flex;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

#search {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  padding: 1em;
  border:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="search-row">
    <input id="search" type="search" placeholder="What instrument do you want to learn"/>
    <button id="submit" type="submit">Search</button>
</div>
```

Anyway, making what you wanted without getting into much trouble is easy too:

```css
#search-row {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  position:relative;
}

#search {
  width:100%;
  padding: 1em; padding-right: 80px; 
  border:0; 
}

#submit{
 position:absolute;
 right:1em; 
  top:50%; transform:translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="search-row">
    <input id="search" type="search" placeholder="What instrument do you want to learn"/>
    <button id="submit" type="submit">Search</button>
</div>
```

Just make sure to adjust the padding-righ on your #search so the text won't get behind the button, and the X button for the browser autocomplete stays left of the button. And use the classic top:50% transform:translateY(-50%) to center the button

Comment: @Shoukran I've added an option to do what you were asking for in the first place, plus some notes on how to prevent the related problems. If it works for you, remember to upvote and mark the answer as accepted

Comment: I will, however my original problem is not with the text going behind the button, but the button breaking out of the text box

Comment: @Shoukran check my second solution. That's pretty much what you were trying to make in the first place, only the button staying where it should ;)

Answer (score 0):

you Refer This link Best Solution.

https://jsfiddle.net/1jxkyLdv/

Demo code here.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 1rem;
}

h1 {
  margin: 2rem 0 0;
}


/* Flexbox Example 
    **************************************************************************/

.flexbox {
  display: flex;
}

.flexbox .stretch {
  flex: 1;
}

.flexbox .normal {
  flex: 0;
  margin: 0 0 0 1rem;
}

.flexbox div input {
  padding: .5em 1em;
  width: 100%;
}

.flexbox div button {
  padding: .5em 1em;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<h1>Short Word</h1>
<section class="flexbox">
  <div class="stretch">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." />
  </div>
  <div class="normal">
    <button>Search</button>
  </div>
</section>

<h1>Long Word</h1>
<section class="flexbox">
  <div class="stretch">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." />
  </div>
  <div class="normal">
    <button>Super Long Word For Search Button With Flexbox!</button>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: This doesnt have the button inside the text box which is what i want